# Why is setInterval only executing once?

Tags: javascript, html

`setInterval` only executes once. I have also tried using `setTimeout` and placing it inside the function to cause a loop, but that gives the same result. I am using brackets and it's live preview if that makes a difference.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

setInterval(charChange, 1000);

function charChange(){
    let string;
    let chars = ['#', '!', '@', '$', '%', '&', '+', '?'];
    for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        string = buttons[i].textContent;
        let char = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
        string = string.replace(/_/, char);
        buttons[i].textContent = string;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id = 'title'>help_</button>
```

Comment: No, it executes every second. Your function just keeps doing the same thing. What's the point of this on button `.textContent` anyways? What is your goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function runs correctly, the problem is in the function code itself, not in `setInterval`.

Doing this:

```
string = string.replace(/_/, char);
```

You're always trying to replace the `_` character. From the second time your function is called, that character will not be present anymore since it got replaced by the first call.

If you want the last character to keep changing, you have multiple options:

```
string = string.substrstring.replace(/.$/, char);
// or
string = string.substrstring.slice(0, -1) + char;
// or even just
buttons[i].textContent = 'help' + char;
```

The regexp `.$` matches any character that is at the last position in the string (`$` matches the end of the string), but it's probably the slowest option.

---

Working snippet:

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

setInterval(charChange, 1000);

function charChange(){
    let string;
    let chars = ['#', '!', '@', '$', '%', '&', '+', '?'];
    for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        let char = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
        buttons[i].textContent = 'help' + char;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id = 'title'>help_</button>
```

Comment: @Craftingexpert1 this is **exactly** the problem. Try it yourself, I added a working code snippet.

Comment: Sorry about that, i didn't see that.